# redesigning an old wwwboard website : How to factor out navigation bar without changing .html extension?

Tags: html, css, object, embed, navigationbar

I'm trying to make an old wwwboard from the 90's look more recent than something from, well, the 90's. There are 46,770 files that will need to be converted. I'll be ripping the content off each page and shoving it into an updated page by using a program I've written in Java, butefore I convert everything over I want to make sure that the template I put the content into can be easily edited in the future.

This is important for navbars, footers, and advertisements. Normally if I was using PHP I would factor out the navbar and header using

```
<?php include ('header.html'); ?>
<?php include ('navbar.html'); ?>
<!--actual content-->
<?php include ('footer.html'); ?>
```

Unfortunately, all the files need to keep their .html file names. So PHP is out of the question. (Correct me if I'm wrong.) 
So instead I attempted to factor out the header and navbar by using

```
<object id="HeaderObj" data="header.html" >
    <embed src="header.html">
</object>
<object id="NavbarObj" data="navbar.html" >
    <embed src="navbar.html">
</object>
```

where both sections would have widths and properties controlled by CSS for easy embed changing in the future. 
[image]

Unfortunately, when you go to click on a link in these embedded pictures, it opens the new link inside the embedded page. It looks like this.
[image]

I can't use the embed tags if they don't give users usable links. Would anyone out there have a solution to my current issue? If I can't figure this out I'll have to run my batch website converter every time we need to make a microscopic change.

Comment: You can allow the execution of PHP in .html pages by using `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html` in an `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Thanks Dawson! This has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm
^This worked for me. Next I'll be making sure there's no chance of PHP injection, or whatever might be possible with PHP as a language.